# Why did an Android update disable  the textures in my game?

Tags: android, textures, opengl-es2

I recently updated my tablet to Android 4.0.3 and now the textures for my game do not show up. I'm using OpenGL-ES 2.0 for my engine. It worked fine when I was running android 3.0.  Is there any reason as to why this is happening?

Comment: How are you loading the textures? What file format are you coming from? You say they aren't showing up -- do you see black instead? Have you tried manually creating a pink (etc) texture in place of your normal ones to see if that shows up?

Comment: thanks for the replies, I actually fixed the problem about an hour after i posted the question,   I'll consider your advice in the future.

Comment: Then you should explain what the problem was so others might benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not terribly well documented, but there are some events which cause an OpenGL context loss on android. Make sure your textures are reloaded after every context loss.